# ArrayAdapter - Resource$notfound

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-adapterview

I have an arrayadapter which populates 4 textfields. In the getView method when it tries to populated the textfields with the values. I get the error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x11.  Could you please guide to the point where it needs correction.

Following is the ArrayAdapter code

```
public class AdapterTicketList extends ArrayAdapter<POJO_Ticket> {
Context context;
ArrayList<POJO_Ticket> ticketArray;
LayoutInflater vi;

public AdapterTicketList(Context context , ArrayList<POJO_Ticket> ticketArray) {    
    super(context, 0, ticketArray );    
    this.ticketArray = new ArrayList<POJO_Ticket>();    
    this.ticketArray.addAll(ticketArray);  
    this.context =context;

    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    }  

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTicketID;  
    TextView tvCreationHour;  
    TextView tvTableNumber;     
    TextView tvAmount;    
    } 

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      
    ViewHolder holder;    
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {                   
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowticket,  null);  
        holder.tvTicketID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTicketID); 
        holder.tvCreationHour = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCreationHour); 
        holder.tvTableNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTableNumber); 
        holder.tvAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);  
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }       
    Ticket ticket =ticketArray.get(position).getTicketObject();

    Log.i("AdapterTicketList"," ticket id : " + ticket.getId()); 
    holder.tvTicketID.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getId())) ;  
    holder.tvCreationHour.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getCreationHour())) ;  
    holder.tvTableNumber.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getTableNumber())) ;   
    holder.tvAmount.setText( String.valueOf((ticket.getTotalAmount())))  ; 
    return convertView; 
    }
```

}

```
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at com.example.restaurent.AdapterTicketList.getView(AdapterTicketList.java:59)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2040)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1870)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1652)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1641)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1417)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1652)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1510)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:443)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1652)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1510)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:443)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-09 00:11:15.337: E/AndroidRuntime(10204): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is correct because you convert the numeric value to a String:

```
holder.tvAmount.setText(Double.toString(ticketArray.get(position).getTicketObject().getTotalAmount())) ;
```

These have have potential problems since they appear to fetch numeric values:

```
holder.tvTicketID.setText(ticketArray.get(position).getTicketObject().getId()) ;  
holder.tvCreationHour.setText(ticketArray.get(position).getTicketObject().getCreationHour()) ;  
holder.tvTableNumber.setText(ticketArray.get(position).getTicketObject().getTableNumber()) ;
```

**Solution:** You *must* pass a String or an appropriate `R.string.xxx` integer to `setText()`.

So use:

```
holder.tvTicketID.setText(String.valueOf(ticketArray.get(position).getTicketObject().getId()));
// etc
```

(You should also consider saving `ticketArray.get(position).getTicketObject()` in a local variable rather than fetching it repeatedly.)

Comment: But Sam.. Other statements are working after converting to string. holder.tvAmount.setText( Double.toString(ticket.getTotalAmount()))  ;   is not working

Comment: Ok, then `ticket.getTotatAmount()` might not be a double. Try `holder.tvAmount.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getTotalAmount()));`, if this doesn't work please post the new LogCat errors.

Comment: It is double. thats is for sure. I tried your code and updated the log

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.restaurent.AdapterTicketList.getView(AdapterTicketList.java:59)` What is line 59?

Comment: holder.tvAmount.setText( String.valueOf((ticket.getTotalAmount())))  ;

Comment: It appears `rowticket.xml` does not have a View with the id `@+id/tvQuantity`... Post `rowticket.xml` if you still need help.